# The "More hot questions" link on a question page refers to the current question, not the hot questions

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, hot-questions

[image]

I thought adding freehand circles would make the question body comply with the imposed standards :(

This happens on every question I looked at (both mine and not mine).

Comment: The # usually indicates a javascript link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click on the "more hot questions" link, then there are just added more links *on the question page itself*, so you are not redirected to another page. When clicking on the link, a JavaScript function gets fired, so that's why the link refers to the current question.

Comment: Ah, that explains. I rightclicked it to open on a new tab each time, which led back to the same question.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel middle click does work, by the way. (try it)